# Can a brokerage hold BUY order from customer until brokerage has needed stock to fill the order "in-house"?

Tags: brokerage, online-brokerage

According to [SEC.gov](https://www.sec.gov/fast-answers/answersinternalizationhtm.html):

> **Internalization**
>
> When you place an order to buy or sell a stock, your broker has
> choices on where to execute your order. Instead of routing your order
> to a market or market-makers for execution, your broker may fill the
> order from the firm's own inventory. This is called "internalization."
> In this way, your broker's firm may make money on the "spread" – which
> is the difference between the purchase price and the sale price.

So from this definition, I've understood that if a broker has a particular stock, it can fill it "in-house" instead of directing it to the open market.

But can a broker hold the BUY order from the customer(one with a big possible spread), until the brokerage purchases needed stock from either its customers or open market and then fill the BUY order to gain the spread profit? I assume that the operation itself will be very fast(to buy the stock at market price) and, probably, not noticeable by a customer.

**Example**: stock costs $100, some customer places an order to buy the stock for $400. A brokerage firm doesn't have the stock in inventory at the current time.

Is it legal? Is it a common practice?

Answer (score 3):

Internalization gives your broker the choice on where to execute your order. It does not give him the right to abuse the order.

In the US, NBBO is also an overriding regulation:

> The [National Best Bid and Offer](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/n/nbbo.asp)  (NBBO) is a Securities Exchange Commission (SEC) regulation requiring brokers to trade at the best available (lowest) ask price and the best available (highest) bid price when buying and selling securities for customers. The National Best Bid and Offer is the bid or ask price that the average customer will see. The Securities and Exchange Commission’s Regulation NMS requires that brokers guarantee their customers this price.

Comment: So a brokerage firm is able to make money on filling an order "in-house" only in case when they bought the exact stock earlier at a price that was lower than the current market's lowest price, right?